# Code Reference Indicator in Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I just tried to find Code Reference Indicator in VS 2013 Professional, but this does not exist in my VS 2013 Pro version.

[image]

How can I find the code reference indicator or install it by any other tool?

**UPDATE**

`code reference indicator` is not available in my VS 2013 version. I am trying to find as described in the following screenshot:

[image]

With the help of this i can find the reference of my method as :

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "code reference indicator" and I don't see anything in your screenshot that matches that description. As a guess: are you talking about [CodeLens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx)?

Comment: @JoeWhite I have updated my question. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about CodeLens.

I believe for vs 2013 you will need Ultimate version to get it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218(v=vs.120).aspx

> Find references to your code
>
> You'll need:
>
> Visual Studio Ultimate
>
> Visual C# .NET or Visual Basic .NET code
>
> The most recent Visual Studio 2013 update so that you can work with solutions that share code across multiple apps

Comment: I cannot update my vs 2013 because this is installed in my office that's why i am trying to find it by another way.

Comment: This is a licencing issue since Microsoft limit the function to certain version.

Comment: So this means i have no other option to enable it?

Comment: @NimitJoshi Ethically, I don't think you can do it.